# Should getters return copies of object instances to avoid side effects?

Tags: java, getter

I want to get a value returned from a function of a class.

Inside my class:

```
public class MyClass {
   private Color color_ = new Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);

   public Color getColor(){
      return this.color_;
   }
}
```

So, in another class of mine, I call

```
this.someOtherColorInOtherClass_=myClass.getColor();
```

If inside `myClass` the `color_` changes though, the color of `someOtherColorInOtherClass_` will also change.

I think this is because in Java everything is a pointer. So basically my getter function returns a pointer to the Color and thus they are both pointing to the same memory location, thus changing the same variable.

In my getter function I could do

```
return new Color(this.color_);
```

and everything would work fine, as I now have a new pointer to work with.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: You have make the distinction between the various possibilities of what you will do with the returned color. Do you want the value returned by the getter to follow the modifications made by the caller? do you want the caller to prevent any modification? (in the first case, you need to return the object it self, in the second case, a deep copy.) If you look at how to make a setter for a list/array object, you'll face the same issues.

Comment: I want the latter case, which means that I do not want to follow the modifications made by the caller. But how (in this case) can I return an object that its Class does not have a copy constructor? Sorry but I have C++ experience where not all objects are pointers in fact.

Comment: various objects have a public `clone` method.

Comment: Please include it as an answer.

Comment: Are you talking about [`java.awt.Color`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)? If yes, how are you changing the values in it?

Comment: I'm talking about `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color` and it provides various functions to change the color, as the `set()`

Comment: Mutability has little benefits in practice and many drawbacks. Go immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, you could have getters return clones and what not but a more robust solution is...

### Immutability

```
If inside myClass the color_ changes though, the color of someOtherColorInOtherClass_ will also change.
```

And this both the intended and the expected behavior. But in your case you'd most likely call this a *nasty side effect*.

This is because `Color` is a *mutable* class, ie. you're free to do:

```
Color color = new Color(r, g, b, alpha1);
...
color.setRGB(r2, g2, b2, alpha2);
...
color.setRGB(r3, g3, b3, alpha3);
```

thus making your `Color` instance vulnerable to state changes.

A counter example is the notable `String` class which is **immutable**. Immutability is a nice feature that is enforced by a number of (functional) languages like Haskell and Scala and which simplifies concurrent programming and has the added bonus of making state-related matters a no-brainer because of its intrinsic **lack of (nasty) side effects**.

Indeed, had you modeled the color field of your two classes as `String`, ie. an immutable class, the issue of sharing the same instance would have been technically safe (and in your case, robust). So the bottom line is, unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, **make your classes immutable**, especially those intended as parameters. Specifically, that means having rich constructors, no setters or private ones if needed and final fields wherever possible. If your getters return potentially mutable instances (eg. like sets/lists/maps or other objects), return [immutable] copies instead.

For instance, a simplified but immutable `Color` class could read (with no getters to avoid boilerplate):

```
public class Color {
    public final double r, g, b, alpha;

    public Color(double r, double g, double b, double alpha) {
        this.r = r;
        this.g = g;
        this.b = b;
        this.alpha = alpha;
    }
}
```

With this `Color` class, any number of objects can share the same color instance without potential side effects. HTH

Comment: @hakermania If you have copy of Effective Java by J. Bloch handy, there's a long chapter on immutability and good practices. Otherwise books on Scala have made it customary to praise immutability and its benefits and they translate [almost] seamlessly into Java. HTH

Comment: What if I want immutability facing the "outside" of the class, but I still want to be able to change the value of the variable from inside the class?