# How to correctly call the functions of a member object inside another object

Tags: java, oop

This is one of the object-oriented design questions from educative.io's OOD course. It asks us to design Amazon i.e. an online shopping system. I am thinking how to incorporate the 4th requirement into the design. Their solution is to create a `ShoppingCart` class and make it a field of `Customer` class. And it seems from the functions provided in their solution that, whenever a user wants to add an item, `Customer.getShoppingCart().addItem()` is called. But since `Customer.getShoppingCart()` is a getter function, it returns a copy of the actual shopping cart. So the item is not added to the correct List. Am I missing something here? How should we correctly delegate the `additem` functionality from `Customer` to `ShoppingCart`[image] [image]

Edit: The best solution I can think of now is make `Customer` extend `ShoppingCart`. Although this is counterintuitive, there's nothing wrong doing so.

Comment: You are mistaken, if `getShoppingCart` is returning the stored instance,  it is not a copy it is the same instance.

Comment: But shouldn't getter functions return a copy of the actual object if that object is mutuable?

Comment: No you want to keep the same instance and just edit it's properties (it is the cart that belongs to the user, the items in it may change).

Comment: @ArleighHix I understand what you mean. I wanted to do the same thing too. But every webpage about getter and setter advise that getter returns a copy to prevent modifying the original object. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23034160/should-getters-return-copies-of-object-instances-to-avoid-side-effects Plus, if we need to modify the  object, why don't we just make the object public?

Comment: You should tag your question with the language your using. I don't know anything about Java, so I cannot really say. If you get a different instance and change it then you need to replace the old one with the new ones in order to keep the changes.

Comment: @ArleighHix Alright thanks for letting me know. Added that tag. Copying and setting takes a lot of time and space complexity. That's the tradeoff here.

Comment: _"But every webpage about getter and setter advise that getter returns a copy to prevent modifying the original object."_ I highly doubt that, and in any case, such advice is contextual. If an object is intended to be modified, then returning a copy will not make much sense, does it, so then you know you should not return a copy (or you will need to design a whole different way of adding items to the cart)

Comment: When you return an internal object for another object to manipulate on, you are breaking the "Law of Demeter".